Parsing structured output and generating a summary about the parsing simultaneously using langchain?
I am using langchain for one of my applications. Here the client sends a query regarding a search criteria. In the app the search criteria gets decomposed into multiple sub search criteria which will be mapped to different search criteria objetcs.
Decomposing
I have a separate decompose chain to do this.
Mapping sub queries
After the decomposition, I run a mapping chain using parallel threads to do the mapping
This is the current setup I have created. I need to generate a reply text for the client based on the query the client sent.
It will be good if I could stream the response while the criteria is being mapped, so that the wait time for the client to receive a response reduces.
Any suggestions to achieve this and to improve the current setup is appropriated. Thanks
I tried to get a summary for each sub query mapping inside the mapped object by adding a summary field, but then I need to run another chain to combine those summaries into a meaningful reply based on the context and history of the session.
